# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to int inside CONCAT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Running this query:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('BL.', IdBL,' - lgn.', LgnBL, ' \ BE.'+BE_Numero_carnet) AS varchar(1000)) AS chemin 
FROM ...
```

Results in an error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '  \ BE.' to data type int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use the +

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT('BL.', IdBL,' - lgn.', LgnBL, ' \ BE.', BE_Numero_carnet) AS     varchar(1000)) AS chemin 
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[codeulike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57076464/3094533) is correct.
This answer is here to provide an explanation on why it is correct.

The `+` operator have a double meaning in SQL Server.
In one meaning, it's a [string concatenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator.
In the other meaning, it's an [arithmetic addition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/add-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator.

Consider the following code:

```
DECLARE @A int = 1, @B int = 2,
        @X char(1) = '1', @Y char(1) = '2';

SELECT  @A + @B As Addition,
        @X + @Y As Concatenation
```

The result, as can be expected, is this:

```
Addition    Concatenation
3           12
```

So far, no surprises.
Now here is where it gets a little tricky: SQL Server makes extensive use of [implicit conversion.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017)

Basically, every time that two different data types are compared, combined, or assigned from one to the other, SQL Server will attempt to implicitly convert one data type to another.
This is not done arbitrarily - SQL Server has a well documented [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table. SQL Server will attempt implicit conversion from the lower data type to the higher, and since `int` is located higher in that table than `char` - it will attempt to convert the `char` to `int`, and will fail if that's impossible.

Using the same variables from the script before:

```
SELECT  @A + @B As Addition,
        @X + @B As ImplicitConversionAndAdition;
```

will result with this:

```
Addition    ImplicitConversionAndAdition
3           3
```

Setting a char value to `@x` that can't be converted to int:

```
SET @X = 'a';

-- Remember: @Y is a char(1)
SELECT @X + @Y As Concatenation;
```

Will result with this:

```
Concatenation
a2
```

However, attempting `@X + @B` will result with a conversion error:

```
SELECT @X + @B As ImplicitConversionFailure
```

Will result with this:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.